# Invalid signature in Authorization header in using Azure Monitor data collector API

Tags: azure, rust, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have translated the [Python example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api?tabs=python#authorization) in the documentation of how to construct the signature required in the Authorization header for requests made to the data collector API, into Rust. My Rust program produces a `SharedKey <workspace_id>:<signature>` that is rejected by the server with code 403 and with the body of the response simply saying

```
{\\\"Error\\\":\\\"InvalidAuthorization\\\",\\\"Message\\\":\\\"An invalid signature was specified in the Authorization header\\\"}
```

On the other hand, I've taken the same date in RFC1123 format from the Rust program execution and hardcoded it in the Python example script. It produces the *exact* same `SharedKey <workspace_id>:<signature>` value for the authorization header and is successful in using the API to send logs.

There is no other information about the nature of the problem with the signature from the Rust program in the response. As far as I can tell, the error is perhaps reporting the wrong problem, since they are exactly the same signature and one works while the other doesn't.

What other reasons could this error type be returned from this API?

I'd be happy to share some Rust code if anyone thinks it's useful, but I am certain that the authorization header from the example Python script in their documentation and my Rust program are identical.  So I feel that it's something else.

*Edit:*  Here is a slightly modified version of Python example from the link above, which is successful in using the API and I see the test message show up in the log analytics workspace:

```py
import requests
import datetime
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

WORKSPACE_ID = "<my workspace ID>"
SHARED_KEY = "<my primary key>"

def build_signature(message, secret):
    key_bytes = base64.b64decode(secret)
    message_bytes = bytes(message, encoding="utf-8")
    hmacsha256 = hmac.new(key_bytes, message_bytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    encoded_hash = base64.b64encode(hmacsha256).decode()
    return encoded_hash

def post_data():
    data = '{"hello":"world"}'
    date_string = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    # date_string = "Thu, 14 Sep 2023 01:27:12 GMT"
    content_length = len(data)
    string_to_hash = f"POST\n{content_length}\napplication/json\nx-ms-date:{date_string}\n/api/logs"
    hashed_string = build_signature(string_to_hash, SHARED_KEY)
    signature = f"SharedKey {WORKSPACE_ID}:{hashed_string}"
    print(signature)

    query = "api-version=2016-04-01";
    url = f"https://{WORKSPACE_ID}.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?{query}"

    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': signature,
        'Log-Type': "my-event-type",
        'x-ms-date': date_string
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    if (response.status_code >= 200 and response.status_code <= 299):
        print('Accepted')
    else:
        print("Response: {}".format(response.content))
        print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    post_data()
```

Here is my Rust version that produces the exact same authorization header value, yet an `InvalidAuthorization` error when trying to use it:

```rust
use base64;
use chrono::Utc;
use ring::hmac;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Error)]
enum MyError {
    MessageSendError(String),
}

struct SentinelClient {
    azure_collector_url: String,
    workspace_id: String,
    shared_key: String,
    http_client: reqwest::Client,
}

impl SentinelClient {
    fn new(workspace_id: String, shared_key: String) -> Self {
        let query = "api-version=2016-04-01";
        let azure_collector_url =
            format!("https://{workspace_id}.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?{query}");
        Self {
            azure_collector_url,
            workspace_id,
            shared_key,
            http_client: reqwest::Client::new(),
        }
    }

    fn send(&self, data: String) -> Result<(), MyError> {
        let workspace_id = &self.workspace_id;
        let date_string = format!("{}", Utc::now().format("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"));
        println!("date string {}", date_string);
        let content_length = data.to_string().len();
        let string_to_hash =
            format!("POST\n{content_length}\napplication/json\nx-ms-date:{date_string}\n/api/logs");
        let hashed_string = Self::build_signature(&string_to_hash, &self.shared_key)?;
        let signature = format!("SharedKey {workspace_id}:{hashed_string}");
        println!("{}", signature);

        let url = &self.azure_collector_url;
        let request = self
            .http_client
            .post(url)
            .json(&data)
            .header("Authorization", signature)
            .header("Log-Type", "my-event-type")
            .header("x-ms-date", date_string);

        match request.send().await {
            Ok(resp) => {
                if resp.status().is_success() {
                    println!("request successful: {:?}", &resp);
                    Ok(())
                } else {
                    let body = resp
                        .text()
                        .await
                        .map_err(|e| SinkError::MessageSendError(e.to_string()))?;
                    println!("request unsuccessful: {body}");
                    Err(MyError::MessageSendError(body))
                }
            }
            Err(e) => Err(MyError::MessageSendError(e.to_string())),
    }

    /// Build the API signature for the Azure Monitor HTTP Data Collector
    /// authorization header.
    ///
    /// See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api?tabs=python#authorization.
    fn build_signature(message: &str, secret: &str) -> Result<String, MyError> {
        let key_bytes = base64::decode(secret).map_err(|e| {
            MyError::MessageSendError(format!("could not decode shared key: {e}"))
        })?;
        let message_bytes = message.as_bytes();
        let hmacsha256 = hmac::Key::new(hmac::HMAC_SHA256, &key_bytes);
        let encoded_hash = base64::encode(hmac::sign(&hmacsha256, message_bytes).as_ref());

        Ok(encoded_hash)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am told that the JSON request body must be utf-8 encoded, otherwise the server rejects the request with a 403 Unauthorized, which seems incredibly misleading.  In my case, the request body was a Rust `String` representing a JSON object, which *is* utf-8 encoded, and which I was passing as the request body via

```rust
http_client.post(url).json(&data)
```

It's unclear to me yet why this works instead,

```rust
http_client
    .post(url)
    .body(data)
    .header(reqwest::header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
```

since I was under the impression that the `json` method did exactly that.  But the `json` method must do something with how the data is encoded that `body` does not.

Comment: If you do `.json(&data)` when `data` is a `String`, the JSON encoding will add quotes around your content and add slashes before some characters (because that's how you encode strings into JSON), so if your content was already encoded as JSON, then this will probably be unexpected by the server (it will get a JSON string instead of a JSON object). Your workaround means it will pass your content as-is with the correct JSON content type without additional encoding.